# Read contents of ZIP file via URLs

Tags: javascript, node.js, zip, electron, node-webkit

I am wrapping a web app into a desktop app with Electron.  Is there any solution, which would allow loading files from the ZIP archive via URLs, like so:

```
<img src='./archive.zip/somefile.jpg'>
```

I know this is possible with Electron's ASAR archive format (https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/application-packaging.md).  How this can be done in node.js or NW.js, would also be relevant.

Comment: Did you look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/jszip

Comment: I think that package only allows accessing stuff inside the zip file via API funciton calls.  I would like to be able to treat the ZIP file as a virtual folder so that something like this works: <img src='./archive.zip/somefile.jpg'>

Comment: Do you want to parse that uri with js and update it to something like a data uri?  If so then I think that package will allow you to read the zip file.  If you are looking for the browser to naively understand how to read a file within a zip archive then you are going to need a plug-in.

Comment: I'm not building a browser application, so I have a lot more flexibility.  I am wrapping an existing browser app into a desktop app with Electron.  And, yes, I would like to have uri access to all files within a zip.